# cascading dropdown by jsf

Tags: ajax, events, jsf-2

is it possible to update the subCategories by Category selectMenu  onchange by passing category obj?

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="expenseTypeValue"
                            value="#{expenseBean.expense.expenseType}"
                            disabled="#{expenseBean.dataVisible}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{expenseBean.parentCategoryItems}"
                                var="parentCategory1"
                                itemLabel="#{parentCategory1.expenseCategoryDesc}"
                                itemValue="#{parentCategory1.expenseCategoryId}" />
                            <f:attribute name="parentCategory"
                                value="#{expenseBean.parentCategory1}"></f:attribute>
                            <p:ajax update="subCategory"
                                listener="#{expenseBean.getSubCategory(parentCategory1)}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass a property of a bean back to the very same bean which already holds the property? Just access that property locally in the listener method? Aren't you making some logic mistake here? In any way, the concrete question as stated in the title is already answered in among others our `[selectonemenu]` wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info (at the very bottom).

Comment: i refered that i did like ur sample countries & cites also.. i may not sure converter issue selectMenu comes empty

Comment: Just return `null` from converter then?